# Table space used too heavy

Tags: sql-server, diskspace

I have a SQL Server database where space used is too heavy for a log table from a particular application.

Analizing disk usage appears that disk usage for primary key index is what is consuming space.

Primary key is consuming 200k for each row, which appears to be too much.
On different instances of the same application the same primary key uses 20k to 40k for each row.

What can be done to reduce disk usage? It is a log table, we can rebuild/truncate etc. (actually it has been done already) 
There is no concern on keeping data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[logs](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [table] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [operation] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [query] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [post] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [script_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [query_string] [varchar](1024) NULL,
    [user_agent] [varchar](200) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_logs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
    i.name AS IndexName,
    i.index_id AS IndexID,
    8 * SUM(a.used_pages) AS 'Indexsize(KB)',
    ck.total,
    8 * SUM(a.used_pages) / ck.total AS 'Indexsize(KB)/row'
FROM sys.indexes AS i
JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID AND p.index_id = i.index_id
JOIN sys.allocation_units AS a ON a.container_id = p.partition_id
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM logs) ck ON 1 = 1
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) = 'logs'
GROUP BY i.OBJECT_ID,i.index_id,i.name,ck.total
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID),i.index_id
```

Comment: not related to your problem but instead of hacking `JOIN` with `ON 1 = 1` do `CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM logs) ck`

Comment: `[...]200k for each row`; 200k what exactly? 200 kilo-bytes? For each row? For a primary key on an IDENTITY column? I have a hard time believing that. What leads you to conclude that statement?

Comment: @TT. `20k to 40k` for row doesnt sound right neither

Comment: I realize 20-40k is also too much, but we are dealing with this particular instance where pk is consuming much more disk space. Thist table receives 5000 inputs each day. Do the math and you will see the size of the problem. Ideally we want to keep logs for the last 90 days.
I posted above the query analizing disk space.

Comment: So you still claim 200kb per row for index usage? so 200kb times 5000 a day, your index grows by 1,000,000 kb a day? That's ±1,000 Mb, or ±1Gb a day just for the index? I think not!

Comment: You may think not, but this table is increasing 1Gb per day, that is a fact, and we cant figure out why, that's why I opened this post hoping to get some help.

Comment: Looking at [sys.allocation_units](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms189792.aspx), column `used_pages`: "Number of total pages actually in use". A page is not the same as Kb/8. I have no idea how large a page would be but I'm guessing in the order of 4096bytes? I think you are misinterpreting the data...

Comment: Ok, your database grows by 1Gb/day. But your database has more tables than just the log table I assume. There are plenty things online to find the actual size tables take (or indices). Take a backup from yesterday and today, compare the numbers to see where the difference comes from. A (clustered) index on an IDENTITY field is not the culprit, definitely not when only 5000 rows are inserted in the table.

Comment: maybe my query is wrong, but yesterday we truncated this table with 100000 rows and the database reduced from 10Gb to 30Mb. The problem is defintly with this table

Comment: I see two columns that are `VARCHAR(MAX)` (`query` & `post`). Perhaps you should analyze the lengths of what is added there. Maybe what is put in those columns contributes to explosion in size of the table?

Comment: hey guys tks for the comments, looks like controlling the input on varchar(max) cols is leaving the situation under control

Comment: I will not vote to close it, though I think you would get a better assistance on http://dba.stackexchange.com